# How to use a for loop inside a return method?

Tags: java, return

For this program, I am struggling to create a for loop inside the return method ("notString"). I am trying to get the program to ask for a name six times; however, I get an error which tells me to add a return value, which is inside the for loop.

This is the statement from which I have to create a program: Given a string, return a new string where "not " has been added to the front. However, if the string already begins with "not", return the string unchanged.

```
import java.util.*;
 public class practice1 {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    String answer= notString(sc);
    System.out.println(answer);

}
public static String notString(Scanner sc){
    for(int i=0; i<=6;i++){
      System.out.println("Input Name: ");
      String name= sc.nextLine();
      if(name.startsWith("not")){
          return name;
      }else 
          return "not"+name ;
      }
    }

}
```

Comment: If you look at your code you will see that it is `return`ing unconditionally within the for loop - what is the point of having a loop at all?

Comment: Do you want to actually _record_ six names, or are you planning to allow up to six attempts for a certain input?

Comment: I was planning on taking multiple inputs from the scanner.

Comment: so it should store the names in a String array ?

Comment: Yeah, I think that's what I should probably do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two aspects to this question.

The first aspect is that the Java compiler is telling you that it "thinks" that there are ways for your method to end without doing an explicit return.

In reality, that is not so.  It is possible prove that there is no way that the code after the loop (as written) can be reached.

**However**, according to the JLS *code reachability* rules that the compiler is required to implement, it is possible to reach the end of the method.  Therefore, there *has to be* a `return` statement after the loop.

But the deeper aspect is that what you are doing is wrong.  What you have written *will not* ask for a string six times, as it is required to do.

What it will actually do is "give up" after asking just once.  The `return` statement says "return NOW".  And where you have placed the `return` statements, you are returning "NOW" if something is `true` or if it is `false`; i.e. *always*.

If you want to ask six times then either:

- don't return from the middle of the loop, or
- move the loop to the main method.

I can't tell you which of those is the right approach because your explanation of what your program is supposed / required to do is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you must have a return statement for the method notString() which promises to return a String in the method signature.  The following program would compile and run (although I am not sure if it would be your final program):

Modified program:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Practice1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        String answer= notString(sc);
        System.out.println(answer);

    }
    public static String notString(Scanner sc) {
        String answer = "";
        for(int i=0; i<=6; i++){
            System.out.println("Input Name: ");
            String name= sc.nextLine();
            if(name.startsWith("not")){
                return name;
            } else { 
                return "not" + name;
            }

        }
        return answer;  // Problem 2: missed a return statement
    }                   // Problem 1: missed a closing brace
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The program is wrong in both syntax and in construction. There is no point of having a method and passing the scanner object in this case. If you just want to print the 6 inputs as an when they come do this.

```
import java.util.*;
public class practice1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i=0; i<=6;i++){
            String temp = sc.nextLine();
            String answer = temp.startsWith("not")?temp : "not" + temp;
            System.out.println(answer);
        }
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

if you want to store them in an array and print them later at once do this.

```
import java.util.*;
public class practice1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] names = new String[6];
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i=0; i<=6;i++){
            String temp = sc.nextLine();
            String answer = temp.startsWith("not")?temp : "not" + temp;
            names[i] = answer;
        }
        scanner.close();

        for(String name : names){
            System.out.println(name);
        }

    }
}
```